# Regex not working with certain string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to use regex to find `\n` in this string:

```
var str = "<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">test\ntest</span>";
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));
```

which doesn't work.

But, when I try this with `'<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">test\ntest</span>'` it does replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape the quotes inside your string:

```
var str = "<span style=\"color:#FFFFFF;\">test\ntest</span>";
```

Or use the single-quote (which I'm not sure why you said the doesn't work).

Here is an example for both options:

```js
var str = '<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">test\ntest</span>';
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));

var str = "<span style=\"color:#FFFFFF;\">test\ntest</span>";
console.log(str.replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));
```

Comment: the single quotes do work, and thanks for the answer. I didn't know I had to escape them.

Comment: If you don't escape them the parser will think that the string is finished the next time he will see the same type of quote, so the string you have is `"<span style="`, and everything after this is code (which is not your case, this is why you got syntax error). Btw - if you check your original question and look at the colors of the code - you will see that something is odd there...